# Can the default path to user's install settings.xml (${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml) be changed?

Tags: maven

When outside of a project, with no pom.xml, is it possible to change where Maven expects the user settings, always? As in, from a terminal window in the user's home directory?

I have been reading for days but I can't find an answer on  the apache site, google, or here. In https://maven.apache.org/settings.html it says:

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> ```
> The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
> A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
> ```

I want to change the actual configuration of Maven installation/program on my machine to look for the user's settings somewhere else, always: `/home/userFoo/bin/maven.config.directory/settings.xml` instead of `/home/userFoo/.m2/settings.xml`

The settings.xml file says:

```
<!--
 | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
 |
 |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user,
 |                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
```

But when I run that command, mvn -s `/home/userFoo/bin/maven.config.directory/settings.xml` i get many errors.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking: 1. do you want to specify a path to a custom settings (so with the `-s` option), while still keeping the `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` as default (which would be used without `-s`)? 2. Or do you want to override that default so that Maven always considers your new settings without any `-s` declaration?

Comment: I want to override where Maven looks for the user-defined settings: instead  of `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` to tell Maven to ALWAYS look for user-defined settings in the new location. I will edit the question, thanks!

Comment: There is no real good way to do this. The simplest option is either to have a symlink like you did, or create an alias for the `mvn` script that always appends `-s ...`, like `alias mvn='mvn -s ...'`

Comment: You can set `MAVEN_OPTS` to override `user.home` in the JVM. `export MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.home=/home/userFoo/bin/maven.config.directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the command:

```
mvn --settings /home/userFoo/bin/maven.config.directory/settings.xml archetype:generate
```

You can verify if your custom settings file is being loaded by checking the output of the command:

```
mvn --settings /home/userFoo/bin/maven.config.directory/settings.xml help:effective-settings
```

Even the default global settings file location can be changed if you want that to be loaded from a shared location by appending to the above command before the goal:

```
--global-settings /${shared.location}/settings.xml
```

You may also want to create an alias for the command in case you do not want to enter it every time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When I try this the CLI says: [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/userFoo). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Comment: Does this mean to run 'mvn -s' commands or 'mvn -gs' commands I MUST have a pom.xml file where I run the commands? I thought the settings command was like changing the settings for any other program, not project/build specific.. Maybe this is where i went wrong?

Comment: I have update the answer to use a goal that would help you create a new project. The goal "archetype:generate" is just a simple example as it does not require any existing project and can be executed in a blank directory. You may use any other goals such as package or install instead.

Comment: the same can be achieved using your earlier 'mvn -s' as well as 'mvn -gs' commands. The POM is not required if your are using "archetype:generate" or any of the help:**** goals as they do not depend on any existing project

Comment: Will try this tonight and leave feedback! Thank you!

Comment: If the above answer has resolved this query can you mark it as answered? You can always ask another question if you face further issues.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answer. After much consideration this is not what I was trying to do. I want to tell maven to always look for .m2 at another location. Your solution lets me generate a new project stub and the second command does a similar thing but they ignore the local repository location in my settings.xml

I have found the only work around is through symbolic links or an alias like the other user commented on the question.

Comment: Due to the time spent by you and the overall helpfulness of this question I must accept it. Thank you very much I learned a lot more about how things fit together with maven through your answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. The .m2 path is relative to the user home folder which is retrieved in a platform independent manner and also this is the folder where there are least chances of encountering file based permission issues. But you can override that location by overriding the environment variable by explicitly specifying the location through the parameter "-Duser.home" in the mvn command line. Note that this would cause all other java classes in that mvn runtime to interpret the new path as the user home which may have unintended consequences.

Comment: Awesome, this is truly the icing on the cake! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can set `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to override `user.home` in the JVM.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.home=/home/userFoo/bin/maven.config.directory
# do something with Maven
mvn dependency:list
```

or Windows

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.home=D:\home\userFoo\bin\maven.config.directory
:: do something with Maven
mvn dependency:list
```

You can also add `MAVEN_OPTS` to your .bashrc, .profile, or Windows Environment.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this here because it is the only way I can make it work, but it feels wrong:

Make a soft link at ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml with:

```
ln -s ~/.m2/settings.xml ~/bin/maven.config.directory/settings.xml
```